# Combining selectors in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery selector which I am using to apply a tooltip to an element:

```
TooltipBuilder.buildRackDisplayTooltip(this.$el, rackInformationListView.render().$el);
```

My element does not have an id. It does not need one because `this.$el` uniquely identifies the element.

I would like to modify my statement such that the selector now matches two elements:

```
//  Doesn't work
var selector = this.$el + this.$el.children('.rackName');
```

I am hoping to trigger a mouseout event only when the mouse leaves `this.$el` or when the mouse enters some, but not all, descendants of `this.$el`

Is it possible to create such an expression without assigning an id to `this.$el`?

If my element had an id, I might use a selector such as:

```
var selector = $('#' + this.el.id + ' ,' + this.el.id + ' > .rackName');
```

although this still seems unnecessarily verbose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine the elements(probably your variable says selector) using [add](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
var selector = this.$el.add(this.$el.children('.rackName'));
```

You can even provide just selector strings to add as well.

```
var selector = this.$el.add('someselector');
```

And to add on for just in the first example, where you are trying to get the children and add parent to it. You can use `var selector = this.$el.children('.rackName').addBack();`, second example you can use `.add()` for distinct selectors.

Comment: `.addBack()` could also be relevant here.

Comment: @32bitkid yes if the chaining start from one place. but this is when you can just add selectors or elements... You don't have to create a chain.

Comment: right on, I wasn't trying to imply that your answer was incorrect. Just augmenting :)

Comment: @32bitkid no.. no.. i understand... :)